# Помехоустойчивое кодирование: есть ли варианты между простым контролем четности и кодом хемминга

Tags: c, передача-данных

Мне необходимо закодировать посылку (8 бит) таким образом, что бы на приемном конце можно было обнаружить ошибки передачи, если таковые были.

Задача по исправлению ошибок не стоит, однако, это было бы здорово, конечно.

Я сейчас вижу два варианта:

1. **Простой и наименее устойчивый (обнаруживается одинарная ошибка)**. Это контроль четности.
2. **Довольно сложный, но очень устойчивый (обнаруживается двойная и исправляется одинарная ошибка, если я не ошибаюсь)**. Код Хемминга 8 бит данных кодируются в 12-битную посылку (4 избыточных бита). Вообще-то классика это, вроде 11-битная посылка из которой получается 7 битов данных, но вроде бы можно закодировать и "лишний" 8й бит.

Я перелопатил довольно много решений кодирования по Хеммингу, но то ли я не понимаю сам принцип, то ли это действительно довольно сложная задача. Времени на отладку у меня не очень много, ресурсы процессора (ATMega48PA @ 1MHz) тоже не дофига, хотя в моем случае явно не лимитирующий фактор.

Чисто интуитивно мне кажется, что код Хемминга для моей избыточен (да и 33% уменьшение скорости передачи тоже напрягает), а контроль четности - недостаточен.

Нет ли решений где-то посередине?

Comment: Может из Википедии что-то подойдёт: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 6):

Для начала вам стоит определиться, какие реально у вас возникают ошибки, и как часто. После этого — насколько сложно повторно запросить и передать повреждённые данные.

Например, если у вас одна ошибка на миллион бит, ошибка состоит в одном повреждённом бите, а данные можно запросить повторно, то контроля чётности хватит за глаза. Если повторный запрос данных очень дорогой, а обработка нужна как можно более быстрая, и она не терпит задержек, то стоит посмотреть в сторону кода Хемминга.

Контроль чётности можно расширить на какое угодно количество битов, если у вас в этом реально есть необходимость, например, можно брать не остаток от деления на 2, а остаток от деления на 4. Тогда алгоритм будет обнаруживать не один битый бит на байт, а два. Можно действовать и в противоположном направлении, например, считать чётность не одного байта, а блоков больше размером: если ошибки возникают крайне редко, а скорость очень критична, это может быть выгодно.